# Align list items by their bounding rect

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list that uses `display: inline-flex`. The font-sizes of different items in the list are different. I discover that the list items are aligned according to the position of the bottom of the text. This makes the items with the smaller text sizes to appear lower than the others.

However, I want to align the items by the base of their bounding rects.

I have have found a hack to resolve this: I place a span containing a dot either side of the text I want to show, I set the `font-size` of this dot to size of the largest font-size in the list, and I set the `visibility` of these spans to `hidden`.

Is there a non-hacky, pure CSS way to achieve this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juqkqwwL/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
}

li:last-child {
  font-size: 16px;
}

span {
  font-size: 64px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47px;
  width: 204px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>THREE</li>
</ul>

<hr>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li><span>.</span>THREE<span>.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nope...there is no CSS property that can do this. The space above/below fonts is there for a reason. You could experiment with **font-specific** line-heights but that way lies madness.

Comment: I've added `flex` to the container and the items appear to align -- https://jsfiddle.net/LgLs556m/1/ -- is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @sol `flex` in the container does exactly what I want. Thank you. Would you like to add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the alignment you want by adding `display: flex` to the container, in this case the `ul` element.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LgLs556m/1/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
}

li:last-child {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>THREE</li>
</ul>
```